# Требуют лишить актера роли. Порядок слов правильный?

Tags: порядок-слов

Актера требуют лишить роли.

Требуют лишить актера роли.

Требуют актера лишить роли.

Имеется в виду, что высказываются требования о том, чтобы актера лишили роли, но нужен короткий заголовок. Порядок слов во втором варианте кажется правильным. Но будет ли большой ошибкой, если выбрать первый вариант?

Comment: Мне тоже нравится выбранный Вами вариант. Будет ли большой трагедией если где-то напишут/напечатают другой? Да вряд ли. Куда более печальные вещи происходят каждый день. В следующий раз пишите правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Требуют отнять у актёра роль. Может, так?

Из ваших вариантов лчшим является действительно второй: *Требуют лишить актёра роли*. Оба существительных зависят от глагола *лишить*, стоят после него - удобно.  И форма родительного падежа находящихся рядом существительных - одушевлённого и неодушевлённого - не настораживает. Первый вариант тоже возможен, ошибки нет.

Answer (score 1):

Де-юре второй вариант правильный, не спорю. В нем нет даже намека на то понимание, что "тебуют (от) кого". Но если говорить о броскости заголовка, то порядок слов удачнее в первом варианте. Актер как акцентный центр высказывания вынесен на первое место. При этом двусмысленность хоть и есть, но все же достаточно маловероятна. Смысл понятен, как порядок слов ни меняй. Так что я за первый вариант.